# XSLT transformation does not keep the indents

Tags: xml, xslt, jaxp

I am new to XSLT and trying to remove some element from a xml.  Here is the code of XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff id="tomcat">
        <firstname>tomcat</firstname>
        <lastname>kingdong</lastname>
        <nickname>cat</nickname>
        <salary>900000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="lvshi">
        <firstname>lvshi</firstname>
        <lastname>Laong</lastname>
        <nickname>dog</nickname>
        <salary>800000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

and here is the xsl code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="staff[@id='tomcat']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the intention is to remove the first staff element and white space line coming with that. 
Then I run this Java code in JAXP (those inputXML, stylingXSL, etc are just some variables.)

```
File datafile   = new File(inputXML);
File stylesheet = new File(stylingXSL);

DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
document = parser.parse(datafile);

TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outputXML);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Then this is what I got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><company>
<staff id="lvshi">
<firstname>lvshi</firstname>
<lastname>Laong</lastname>
<nickname>dog</nickname>
<salary>800000</salary>
</staff>
</company>
```

Bascially the problem is

1) the starting tag of root element  is now at the tail of the declaration;

2) no indent is kept as expected.

Please help.

Comment: Works fine for me in Saxon 9 and Saxon 6.  What happens if you remove the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` tag?

Comment: @Garrison Without that, there would be a big chunk of empty lines after removal of the element. And even if I don't include that tag, the problem 1 still exists.

Comment: The default transformer in Java may not give you that level of control. Remember, XML is designed to be readable by another process, and human readability is a secondary goal.  The output you show is perfectly acceptable vis-a-vis the standards.  You may not have any solution other than to serialize the output yourself if you need exact formatting.